# Android Listview & Checkbox Issue

Tags: java, android, listview

I am attempting to check my checkbox every time the listview item is clicked. I can't seem to get it to work. I've cut down the code to what I believe is causing my problem:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //What I am trying which does not seem to work
    if(checkBox.isChecked()){
        fld.setToSelected(false);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        fld.setToSelected(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    AutoCompleteTextView auto = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextComplete);
    auto.setText("");

    selectedFriend.add(names.get(position));
    names.get(position);

}
```

FriendListData.java

```
boolean selected = false;

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setToSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

FriendBaseAdapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_item, null);
        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    mViewHolder.friendName = detail(convertView, R.id.friendName, myList.get(position).getFriend());
    mViewHolder.checkedName = detail(convertView, R.id.checkedFriend, myList.get(position).isSelected());

    return convertView;
}


private CheckBox detail(View v, int resId, boolean isChecked){
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(resId);
    checkBox.setChecked(isChecked);
    return checkBox;

}
```

friend_item.xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkedFriend"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>
```

All help is appreciated. If more code is needed, please ask.

Comment: Do you have one checkbox in your MainActivity layout? Or one checkbox per list item?

Comment: @dthacker One checkbox per list item.

Comment: what doesn't work? checkbox does not change state? click in list item is not detected?

Comment: @Mikel The checkbox does not change state. The list item is clickable and does what it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onListItemClick(), at least have this code:

```
checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkedFriend);
...
checkBox.setChecked(true);
```

Notice I am referencing the parameter view (v) to find the **correct Checkbox** in the Listview row.

I know you're cutting code down, but at this point we're trying to find bugs. So the full code may save time in this case.

Comment: With a modification to my if/else and your advice, this did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `CheckBox` to be clicked when the whole list item is clicked you need to add `android:duplicateParentState="true"`

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkedFriend"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
```

This will make it so every time the list item is clicked all children marked with `android:duplicateParentState=true` will also receive click events.

Note that if your `CheckBox` is nested inside of multiple view groups you will have to add the `duplicateParentState` flag for each `ViewGroup` it is a part of.